# How do i add child property with jquery all at once?

Tags: jquery, css

How do i add child property with jquery all at once? i'm trying such as below code but doesnt work.

CSS:

```
.item > ul
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.item > span
{
  color:gray;
}
.item > span:hover
{
  color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <span>Text</span>
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".container").addClass("item");
```

Comment: your jquery code seems fine. You only wrote `marign` instead of `margin`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just looking for:

```
$(".container").children().addClass("item");
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

If you're wanting to apply it to all children and not just immediate children, you'll have to do it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

WHen is this code running. If you are executing it after the page (DOM) loads using the chrome console or firebug you should see a change. Otherwise you should be placing this in a Ready handler in your script body on the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

The problem is the JS often fires before the DOM has loaded so this element and its class you are using as a selector doesn't exist to query yet.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not really make clear if you want the item class to be added to *all* children.

If that is the case, this is one way to do it.

```
$('.container').children().each(function(){
    if($(this).has('li'))
       $(this).children().addClass('item');
    $(this).addClass('item');
});
```

This will add the item-class to all of the children even the LI's in the UL. :)

See [this tinker](https://tinker.io/29a99/1)